# I don't understand React.js's onMouseEnter event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code

```
import React from "react"

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img onMouseEnter={() => console.log("entered")} src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Why does this work only for the first time I hover on the image, so no matter how many times I enter or leave the image with my mouse I will get only one "entered" printed into the console.
But for some reason if I change it to:

```
<img id="imga" onMouseLeave={() => console.log("left")} onMouseEnter={() => console.log("ent")} src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100" />
```

i.e. I add also an onMouseLeave event then it works just fine and I get "enter" printed to the console every time I hover on the image with my mouse.
Could anyone please explain to me this behavior? How to get the onMouseEnter event fired every time on mouse hover without using onMouseLeave?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

onMouseOver={() => **{** console.log('mouse over'); **}**}

Comment: I've already tried to replace it with onMouseOver but the problem remained and I had to add onMouseOut for it to work in the way I wanted.

Comment: The problem is not over or enter , the problem is you must enclose console.log into embraces. See bold embraces arround console.log. replace onmouseover by onmouseenter in my example. Hope it can help you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I copy-pasted your code but it doesn't work neither. Then I have changed my browser from Firefox to Chrome and now it works. It works also in Opera. It seems that there is maybe a Firefox-related bug in React's implementation?

Comment: So I launched this app on a different operating system (Linux Mint) and it' exactly the same: It works in Chrome but fails in Firefox. So this must be a bug.